# Error on [civicrm.root] as CiviCRM Resource URL

Tags: resource-urls

After upgrading to 5.23.0, I am getting the error that my resource URL is not correct. Everything seems to be okay though.

In the admin section, the Civicrm Resource URL is [civicrm.root]/

In civicrm.settings.php:

> $civicrm_root =
>   '/home/myuser/domains/mydomain/private_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm';

Answer (score 4):

Mistake by myself: there should be a slash at the end of the variable:

> $civicrm_root =
>   '/home/myuser/domains/mydomain/private_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/';

Comment: Mark this as the accepted answer :-)